# Update resource in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I need to update a resource inside a BizTalk application. It is a BizTalk project that contains maps (btm and xslt). Manual steps to do this are -

-Build the project 
-Copy the dll to application path on the BizTalk server (Ex. C:\Program Files (x86)\MyBizTalkApp\bin) 
-Goto BizTalk application-->Resources-->Right click on that resource-->Modify 
-Click on Refresh-->Select the updated dll from the application path (copied in the previous step) and click on Refresh.
-Check "Add to GAC on add resource" and click OK 
-Restart host instance

How can these be achieved using scripts? Does using BTSTask.exe to add resource do ALL the above steps (including host instance restart)?

Comment: 1) You know you can use Deploy from Visual Studio to update it right?  2) Have you looked at using BizTalk PowerShell Provider or BizTalk Deployment Framework?

Comment: This is for production deployment, so VS is not an option. I wrote batch scripts to copy files and GAC using gacutil.exe and then restart host instances

Comment: Does this answer your question? [During biztalk deploy when it is not requred to import msi via console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524054/during-biztalk-deploy-when-it-is-not-requred-to-import-msi-via-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **NOT** use the above approach from production.  That is just a recipe for disaster as it just takes one person forgetting to include a DLL or forgetting to do one of the steps to cause some very strange and hard to diagnose issues.

At the very least you should be creating MSIs including all DLLs from your Development environment, and importing/installing those.

Better would be creating MSIs using a build server that gets the code from source control and creates a package. This also helps to eliminate the lost code due to some developer not checking in code.

You may want to look at such things us the BizTalk Deployment Framework or PowerShell Provider for BizTalk to automate as much of the deployment as possible.

At best you can use the above with other deployment frameworks such as Octopus Deploy, Azure DevOps or Team City to reach the ideal which is CI/CD (Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment)