# How to deployment dll manually in resource Biztalk Server 2016?

Tags: windows-installer, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper, vdproj

Can anyone help to deploy Biztalk application on Biztalk server 2016 manually.
My code has one .csproj and one .btproj file. Application was already deployed via Visual studio 2015 by installing Visual studio 2015 on Biztalk server and deploying it from visual studio (working fine).

But now we can't use VS 2015 on server, so i have installed Biztalk server 2016 and Visual studio 2015 on our developer machine. whenever i build my solution  dll is created. i want to deploy that dll on server manually  by pasting that dll in resources path in Biztalk server configured for application, but dll changes are not reflecting (it seems target location is not getting refreshed)

how i could deploy my dll manually without installer(.msi)?

Apart from above approach i have also created one installer using .vdproj project, but again that installer is just pasting dll on requested path, so i am trying to deploy manually.
i tried to paste my dll on resource path but dll changes not reflecting on application.

I am expecting  to deploy my updates for biztalk application with minimum efforts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update resource in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825715/update-resource-in-biztalk)

Comment: At the very minimum you need to import the DLL via the BizTalk Admin console and GAC it.  But as per my two answers on the topic, I would not recommend this for Production deployments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And why can't you use Visual Studio 2015?  That is the only supported version to develop and deploy BizTalk 2016 solutions.  Also have you looked at using BTDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the admin console go to the application, resources and right click and add resource, make sure you select GAC on Add, and click Add.

Note that this is not the recommended procedure for Production as outlined in

- [Update resource in BizTalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825715/update-resource-in-biztalk)
- [During BizTalk deploy when it is not required to import MIS via console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524054/during-biztalk-deploy-when-it-is-not-requred-to-import-msi-via-console/50573587#50573587)

.